# HTTPd shows PHP code instead of executing it

Tags: centos, php, apache-httpd

My setup:

```
# grep php /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf 
LoadModule php5_module  modules/libphp5.so
AddType x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler php5-script .php

# grep PHP /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf 
PHPIniDir /etc/

# grep open_tag /etc/php.ini 
; short_open_tag
short_open_tag = On

# /etc/init.d/httpd start
Starting httpd: [Tue Dec 04 03:26:29 2012] [warn] module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for holdsworth
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
                                                           [  OK  ]

# cat /var/log/httpd/error_log 
[Tue Dec 04 03:26:37 2012] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Tue Dec 04 03:26:37 2012] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Dec 04 03:26:37 2012] [warn] module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
[Tue Dec 04 03:26:45 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Dec 04 03:26:45 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Dec 04 03:26:53 2012] [warn] ./mod_dnssd.c: No services found to register
[Tue Dec 04 03:26:53 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 04 03:28:35 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

access_log is empty. When I open index.php, it shows its content.

```
[root@holdsworth steve]# ls -lah /var/www/html/php/index.php 
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 1.7K Oct 31 18:38 /var/www/html/php/index.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to clear browser cache, i.e. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd>

php was working, but browser was giving me old version of php content.

Answer (score 4):

Appears you have both **suEXEC** and **SELinux** enabled, so you will need to hack around to permit execution of the **php** script, to start off check **CGI** scripts are permitted:

```
getsebool -a | egrep 'cgi|builtin_scriptin'
```

If not:

```
setsebool -P httpd_enable_cgi 1
setsebool -P httpd_builtin_scripting 1
```

Also check the php scripts have the necessary extended flag, are owned and executable by the apache process, to keep both SElinux and suEXEC happy:

```
ls -lZ *.php

chcon -t httpd_sys_script_exec_t *.php
chmod +x *.php
chown  xxxx:yyyyyy  *.php

ls -l *.php
```

Alternatively, if not a public server, disable both.

See: http://beginlinux.com/server_training/web-server/976-apache-and-selinux

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you should find where you're loading mod_php a second time:

```
[warn] module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
```

I am very superstitious about Apache config files with warning messages - they mean more than they say sometimes.

Second, try a different way of getting mod_php to parse files:

```
<IfModule php5_module>
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">          
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>  
</IfModule>
```

Lastly, consider *where* you put the directive(s) to mod_php: if you've got VirtualHost directives, you may have to enable mod_php inside that.

Answer (score 0):

I used your configuration file and added below contents to the end of `httpd.conf` file. `addType`, `AddHandler`, `PHPIniDir`.

And it works for me on CentOS 5, without showing the contents of `index.php`.